# stretch div with top and bottom margins - css/css3

Tags: css

I have a page with divs as below;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="wrap2"></div>
        <div id="wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I have specific height for `wrap2` and i want `wrap` to fill the area below `wrap2` , but above `footer`. You can see the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/ucutJ/1/)**. I want to stretch `wrap` in between `wrap2` and `footer`. I am looking for a pure css solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's a better way to auto adjust the height of your content. e.g. div#wrap grows and shrinks depending on the amount of text it has.

Comment: what do you want changed from your fiddle?

Comment: I have updated my question and fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by setting `padding-bottom: 31px;` for `#content` and by setting a `100% height` for `wrap`.

You can see the result fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/ucutJ/7/)**

Thanks @DA, @Jaspero and @Ima Student

Answer (score 2):

You can't with pure CSS. This is perhaps the single biggest complaint about CSS. The most accurate option would be to use JavaScript. On onload and onresize call a JS function that grabs the height of the viewport, subtracts the height of your footer and header, then sets the height of your div to fill in the rest.

Comment: can u do it using the technique my setting top and bottom and by specifying the position??

Comment: Well, my answer still stands: I don't think there is a pure CSS solution for this.